# How to avoid duplicate values ?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, aggregate-functions

I am new to Mongo Db and would appreciate some help with this query.my mongodb data transection same ids number of thre based on create_date how to display each transection id first record

```
 db.collection.aggregate([{
     {"$project": {
     "RESOURCE_ID": 1,
     "TRANSACTION_ID":1,
     "CREATE_DATE":1
   }}

  ])
```

output:

```
      RESOURCE_ID         TRANSACTION_ID              CREATE_DATE   
1      "100-101"      "0:ffff0a0a0983UY:-142"   "Fri Sep 07 16:51:30IST2018"
2      "100-101"      "0:ffff0a0a0983UY:-142"   "Fri Sep 07 16:51:29IST2018"
3      "100-101"      "0:ffff0a0a0983UY:-142"   "Fri Sep 07 16:51:29IST2018"
4      "100-102"      "0:ffff0a0a0983UY:-111"   "Fri Sep 06 16:51:29IST2018"
5      "100-102"      "0:ffff0a0a0983UY:-111"   "Fri Sep 06 16:51:28IST2018"
```

expected output:

```
       RESOURCE_ID         TRANSACTION_ID              CREATE_DATE   
1      "100-101"      "0:ffff0a0a0983UY:-142"   "Fri Sep 07 16:51:30IST2018"
2      "100-102"      "0:ffff0a0a0983UY:-111"   "Fri Sep 06 16:51:29IST2018"
```

Comment: what have you tried until now?

Comment: using $project iam getting  RESOURCE_ID  and  TRANSACTION_ID   and CREATE_DATE  I am new to Mongo Db devloper i dont have idea each teransection id first record with based on cerate date @  Hagai

Comment: Can you put here the full query that you have tried, and the results it gave you? I'll try to help

Comment: db.collection.aggregate([{

  {"$project": {
     "RESOURCE_ID": 1,
     "TRANSACTION_ID":1,
       "CREATE_DATE":1
   }},

  ]) @ Hagai

Comment: And how do you insert the data? I want to make sure that the format of the dates you insert is actually a date

Comment: hello  Hagai   query updated  data was  automatic inserting with application @  Hagai

Comment: Try `db.collection.aggregate([  {$sort:{'CREATE_DATE':-1}},   {$group:{ _id: '$RESOURCE_ID',doc:{$first:'$$ROOT'}}},  {$replaceRoot:{newRoot:"$doc"}} ])`

Comment: THANKS @  Veeram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:
`db.collection.aggregate([{"$sort": {CREATE_DATE: 1}},{$group:{"_id": "$RESOURCE_ID", TRANSACTION_ID: {$first: "$TRANSACTION_ID"}, "CREATE_DATE": {$first: "$CREATE_DATE"}}}])`

What it does - sorts all the documents by the date, in an ascending order, because we want the oldest document first (notice the `sort` clause).
Then, it groups the documents by the field "RESOURCE_ID" (which is marked as the new `_id`), and takes the `$first` TRANSACTION_ID and `$first` CREATE_DATE.

Notice that you will have to convert your timestamps to actual timestamps, in order for mongo to really understand the order of the timestamps. Otherwise mongo will sort them as strings, and this isn't what you want

An example:

```
> db.collection.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bd2bf353ca22147747ec212"),
    "RESOURCE_ID" : "100-101",
    "TRANSACTION_ID" : "0:ffff0a0a0983UY:-142",
    "CREATE_DATE" : ISODate("2017-10-13T10:53:53Z")
}                                                 
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bd2bf3c3ca22147747ec213"),
    "RESOURCE_ID" : "100-101",
    "TRANSACTION_ID" : "0:ffff0a0a0983UY:-142",
    "CREATE_DATE" : ISODate("2017-10-14T10:53:53Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bd2bf3c3ca22147747ec214"),
    "RESOURCE_ID" : "100-102",
    "TRANSACTION_ID" : "0:ffff0a0a0983UY:-111",
    "CREATE_DATE" : ISODate("2017-10-13T10:53:53Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bd2bf3c3ca22147747ec215"),
    "RESOURCE_ID" : "100-102",
    "TRANSACTION_ID" : "0:ffff0a0a0983UY:-111",
    "CREATE_DATE" : ISODate("2017-10-14T10:53:53Z")
}


> db.collection.aggregate([{"$sort": {CREATE_DATE: 1}},{$group:{"_id": "$RESOURCE_ID", TRANSACTION_ID: {$first: "$TRANSACTION_ID"}, "CREATE_DATE": {$first: "$CREATE_DATE"}}}])
{ "_id" : "100-102", "TRANSACTION_ID" : "0:ffff0a0a0983UY:-111", "CREATE_DATE" : ISODate("2017-10-13T10:53:53Z")
{ "_id" : "100-101", "TRANSACTION_ID" : "0:ffff0a0a0983UY:-142", "CREATE_DATE" : ISODate("2017-10-13T10:53:53Z")
```

Also, worth mentioning that you should add indexes for `CREATE_DATE` because you are sorting by this field, and to `RESOURCE_ID` because mongo has to sort it in order to group by it

Comment: Hello Hagai  small help........@Hagai